# Configurate Keycloak as Identity Broker for login into AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, keycloak, saml

I need to configure Keycloak as identity broker to log with an external IdP into AWS console.
What I'm trying to reach is explained in this picture
[identity brokering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDNaB.png)

I have configured my External IdP in the Identity Provider section in the keycloak admin console. After that I have create a client in keycloak with aws-saml-metadata.xml.
So, after that I have try to log into aws, but I have this error [aws console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkF0v.png)

I have investigate the SAML response and I have notice that the SAML assertion received for AWS is encrypted and of course the mappers that I have created in keycloak client for aws doesn't match because they can't find the attributes needed for the login.
I don't know how to resolve and if the problem depends from the certificate, becuase when I use the private key of the IdP I can decrypt the assertion and I found Session Name, Session Role and Session Duration (AWS mappers).
I uplod my SAML Assertion response got with SAML Tracer

```
<samlp:Response xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
            xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
            Destination="https://signin.aws.amazon.com/saml"
            ID="ID_f60025a6-107e-4682-bfe7-25f8d44f8ac1"
            IssueInstant="2023-09-12T15:33:49.894Z"
            Version="2.0"
            >
<saml:Issuer>https://it-ccv-login-aws-connect.qual.gngtel.aws.generali-cloud.it/realms/SSO-Connect</saml:Issuer>
<dsig:Signature xmlns:dsig="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <dsig:SignedInfo>
        <dsig:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        <dsig:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
        <dsig:Reference URI="#ID_f60025a6-107e-4682-bfe7-25f8d44f8ac1">
            <dsig:Transforms>
                <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                <dsig:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
            </dsig:Transforms>
            <dsig:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
            <dsig:DigestValue>hgBQ5syg8C3QLoX+tEebBmw819fov/50FcnPKbdx/bE=</dsig:DigestValue>
        </dsig:Reference>
    </dsig:SignedInfo>
    <dsig:SignatureValue>jwB/qGHZtlXz+YdZwIN4v0JzYNjCSX/U4am8ceboX77J9M3H2W3NwSmJ42XFsiX/xpU+BoxoR3wjUun9+BrrDgzvQs8PZVFwsw3rb2j1JvlfuxpQupjdT0jN0b87ayluT3hVroHA62W4yj7QXWOPmKOWQfujHhPnGl425Y3mHf+7roFBDd8pRTWFRq2dCb5OgQXUGq0HKe6LeIcXVVs8aYpVtPGAnlwcxhHHmJ3kgbEvZQRvkQAQXn3qAZSAH1ug5rxgvA0IVPswYVgDgpZ/T42Wp39yaTNVHp6QcRR+JeHp6UFlJ3+4Wut+Ez6fdoe8XKZhb8lHOQuZvb81QyHWxQ==</dsig:SignatureValue>
    <dsig:KeyInfo>
        <dsig:X509Data>
            <dsig:X509Certificate>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</dsig:X509Certificate>
        </dsig:X509Data>
    </dsig:KeyInfo>
</dsig:Signature>
<samlp:Status>
    <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
</samlp:Status>
<saml:EncryptedAssertion>
    <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"
                        Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element"
                        >
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc" />
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey>
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p" />
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>LuEppCBP+u9TJtBHW4zwSvm4wovp72Cj2Zk62BegVwHsbc4/L/ssFcUpL6fey7wml8Uqc5NWq33zeTpKTElmX61f2xE4MAsPg9s2/c/0MIeFnKX/NBICWq0+PcwPZxSqQlpNhiQ6g5EGc1/svPXVGcAwi8wPgJdLLC17PWjGpoPtBj0eza/448DBRNZdclVUHY26SwmW8Rxi64NQYz8D8TlsH7IkdM1+sQNuuIarasJhNpsswvZ7vW6+i6z0iep37AOdKDp6S0gO97wgnCEtE7+oJJIQyAhRzM3Rhd+T2x20UmtWoCVuDhLEW+dRJ925Esbf+5+w2riRSVNRQOmlmA==</xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</saml:EncryptedAssertion>
```

</samlp:Response>

I hope the question is clear and you can help me! Thanks